# How to setup package.xml first time for an already running org?

Tags: migration-tool, package.xml

I am working for a company which has already salesforce implemented and I was given the test sandbox and now I am trying to create the package.xml for the first time. Here are few questions I have:

1. How do you create package.xml first time for an org or project?
2. When I did the `retrieveCode` from migration tool it just
       retrieved two classes but where as my org has about 50 classes..not
       sure?

Looks like I need to use `retrieveMetaData` and `describeMetaData` but not sure on how to start these for a new project..

If some body can throw some light on how to setup package.xml for force migration tool for an already successfully running salesforce project that would be so great..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Eclipse / Mavensmate to create the package.xml file, it's the easiest way to gather all components.

[Tquila's Package.xml Builder](https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/) is also handy.

Comment: @Devin, Thanks for the Tquila tool but I have one question: Is there a way to ignore the apex classes the come with the third party apps installed on the org, I just want the components that we created but not bought from appexchange??

Comment: The easiest way would be to just grab the package.xml file & manually remove any namespaced components.